# Telerik Chart Control

Tags: asp.net, charts, telerik

I use telerik chart control in my asp.net application. Is there any way to change chart dynamically with clicking or dragging? If this is possible, I need to get new values of the chart. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the Telerik AJAX RadCharts you can use an OnClick event which enables any bound data series items to be clickable, such as pie segments or bars.

```
<telerik:RadChart runat="server" Autolayout="True" OnClick="RadChart_OnClick" Skin="Black"..
```

You can then handle the click and do whatever you need:

```
protected void RadChart_OnClick(object sender, ChartClickEventArgs args)
{
   if (args.SeriesItem != null)
   {
      int x = args.SeriesItem.Index;
      // your code here
   }
}
```

I'm not aware of any dragging functionality, though.

Check this out: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/chart/examples/functionality/drilldown/defaultcs.aspx